# $\mathcal{I}$ is a proper subset of $R$ if and only if $1 \not \in \mathcal{I}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\mathcal{I}$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Prove that $\mathcal{I}$ is a proper subset of $R$ if and only if $1 \not \in \mathcal{I}$.

Since $R$ is a ring, any ideal is:
1)non-empty

2)must at least contain the element 0 (by the first condition of being a ring)

3)if the ideal has more than one element this means that at least one non-zero element $a$ of the ring must be in the ideal. (because every nonzero element in a field is a unit)

I am having trouble starting with this proof.

After some thought, if I start with the proof of "if $1 \not \in \mathcal{I}$, then $\mathcal{I}$ is a proper subset of $R$." Well this is trivial because if the ideal doesn't contain 1, then it can't be the whole ring since $1\in R$.

However, I still haven't be able to figure out the proof of "if $\mathcal{I}$ is a proper subset of $R$, then $1 \not \in \mathcal{I}$." I know that if $\mathcal{I}$ is a proper subset of $R$, then there is some element of $R$ that can't be in $\mathcal{I}$. But how do I show that is $1$?

Comment: See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperIdeal.html)

Comment: If $1\in I$, then what do you know about $RI$?

Comment: $R=I$ and moreover that it contains inverse elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the contrapositive: show that if $1\in \mathcal{I}$, then $\mathcal{I}=R$.

To do this, it might be easier to answer the following, more concrete, question: what is the ideal generated by $1$?

HINT: Since you seem to have the wrong definition, let me remind you: $X\subseteq R$ is an ideal if

- $0\in X$,
- for all $a, b\in X$, $a+b\in X$, and
- for all $a\in X$ and $b\in R$, $ab\in X$.

Read that last condition carefully . . . now think about what happens if $X$ is an ideal and $1\in X$.

Comment: The ideal generated by $1$ would be $R$ because of all inverse elements would be in the set. Correct?

Comment: Your answer is right, but your justification isn't - what do you mean by "all inverse elements"? Suppose our ring is $\mathbb{Z}$, where there are no nontrivial multiplicative inverses . . .

Comment: Well $1=a\cdot a^{-1}$ or am I assuming too much?

Comment: What if $a^{-1}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Other than the fact $\mathcal{I}\neq R$, I am not sure what other conclusions to make

Comment: That's not a correct conclusion. Go back to the definition: what is the principal ideal generated by $a$ *defined* as?

Comment: I haven't learned what the principal ideal is

Comment: All right, what is the definition of an ideal?

Comment: That is can't be empty and that you have addition and multiplication in the ideal.

Comment: What does "you have addition and multiplication in the ideal" mean? I suspect you mean "the idea is closed under addition and multiplication," but this **is not** correct - while ideals are indeed closed under addition and multiplication, there's more to the definition than that. Read the definition carefully, especially the part about multiplication . . .

Comment: that $xy=yx\in \mathcal{1}$

Comment: @UsernameUnknown What are $x$ and $y$, here? (Also, are we assuming the ring is commutative?)

Comment: elements in the ideal.

Comment: That's not correct. For the second time, **read the whole definition carefully**.

Comment: I provided the definition I am using in the problem

Comment: @UsernameUnknown No, you haven't - I guarantee your book doesn't define ideals this way. (What you've defined is a *non-unital subring*, which is not the same thing as an ideal - and in particular, using this definition, the problem would be *false*, since e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ would be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ under that definition.)